# React native API call returns error code 0 on new iPhones

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

I am working on a RN app who's already deployed on the App and Play Store but isn't currently used. We experienced an issue on the newest iPhones (iPhone 10 and up) where no api calls could be made to our production server.

We have no issues making the same API calls to our development or test server, only our production server always returns an error code 0 (the call is rejected in a few ms).
The server works fine on calls coming from older iphones and from android devices.

I've tried fetch and axios both result in the same problems.

Is there a specific header or permission needed to send api calls from newer iOS devices ?

Thank you !

Comment: Hello @Sinoan,
Have you checked the iPhones' iOS versions? Are they the same?

Also, can you try to call your API from browser with both old and new iPhones?

Comment: @FreakyCoder I've tried calling the API from the browser and it works fine on both devices. The issue seems to appear on iOS 12.4 (on simulator), but i've also experienced it on a real device with iOS 13.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was finally on server side, the SSL Certificate wasn't correctly installed. I've found the problem running curl -v on the api and comparing the result between the production and the test server.

The server returned this :
SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name

We simply reinstalled the certificate and it worked.
As to why the issue only happened on certain iOS versions I don't have the answer, if someone else know why feel free the share the information.

Hoping this can help someone :)